# Determine if it converges or diverges : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {2^n \cdot n!}{1\cdot2\cdots (2n-1)}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Here's the series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {2^n \cdot n!}{1\cdot2\cdots (2n-1)}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$$

Does it converge or diverge ? Thanks

Comment: using ratio test I get $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(n+1)}{(2n+1)}\sqrt{\frac{2n+1}{2n+3}}$$ what was the answer you were aiming for?

Comment: I'm afraid it should be $$\frac{(n+1)}{(2n+1)n} \sqrt{\frac{2n+1}{2n+3}}$$.

Comment: @Vim Cheers, yeah..I just saw that trailing $n$ in my calculation of the paper! Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the question has been answered, so some more thoughts:

- $\frac{n!}{(2n-1)!}=\left(2n\cdot\frac{n!}{2n!}\right)=2n\cdot\frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^n(n+k)}<2n\cdot n^{-n}$

And note how this absorbs $2^n$ to make $2n\cdot \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{-n}$.

And btw. this is a really small quantity.

For the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$, we have

- $2n\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}<\frac{2n}{\sqrt{2n}}=\sqrt{2n}$

Hence

$\frac {2^n \cdot n!}{1\cdot2\cdot...\cdot (2n-1)}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}<\sqrt{2n}\,\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{-n}=c\cdot\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{1/2-n}$

So any presumably divergent remaining sum is smaller than some value of the zeta function on the real line, which are all small.

Answer (score 1):

Using the ratio test I got the ratio is
$$\lambda_n= \frac{(n+1)}{(2n+1)n} \sqrt{\frac{2n+1}{2n+3}}$$
obviously 
$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to +\infty} \lambda_n=0$$
Therefore the sum should converge.